# Need help in extracting a date from a text string via formula in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can someone help me figure out a formula to extract a date?

I would need it for all months and all days with different time (and differing characters in the time/date)

Examples:

```
Tuesday, July 16, 2019 1:00 PM CDT
Tuesday, July 16, 2019 11:00 AM CDT
Monday, August 26, 2019 5:00 PM CDT
```

I just need the date (e.g.: August 26, 2019) so I can compare it to the date in another cell for an exact match. The day of the week is superfluous and the time, I already have a formula to extract that.

This worked for July

```
**A1: Tuesday, July 16, 2019 1:00 PM CDT**

=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+1,8)&", "&MID(A1,FIND("2019",A1),4))
```

But not for August

```
**A1: Monday, August 26, 2019 5:00 PM CDT**

=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+1,8)&", "&MID(A1,FIND("2019",A1),4))
```

This results in “#VALUE” for August dates.

Tried this too:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+1,FIND(",",A1))
```

But resulted in “August”

Any help is appreciated

-FE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This removes the items that keeps excel from recognizing it as a true date time.

Put this in the first cell and copy down then format as desired:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+2,999)," CDT","")
```

[image]

Comment: That did it! WOW. What is the -- before SUBSTITUE for?

Comment: @nossuntlegio it turns the text into a number by multiplying it by `-1` twice.

Comment: Thank you so much!